# How do I call a function in a background script from a broweraction popup?

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions

I want op the options page in a webextension from a link in the browseraction popup.

I have created the file background.js (and included it in the manifest) with this content:

```
function openOptions() {
       browser.runtime.openOptionsPage();
    };

//openOptions()
```

If I call the function directly in the backgroud script it works and the options page opens when the add-on is loaded.

But how do I call this function from a link in the browseraction popup?

In my popup.html I have tried:

```
<a onclick="openOptions()">options</a>
```

That does not work.

I thought that backgroud scripts where available.

Answer (score 1):

You can, but don't need to go all the way to the background page.

in the popup.html

```
<a id="options">options</a>
```

In the popup.js

```
document.querySelector('#options').addEventListener('click', () => browser.runtime.openOptionsPage());
```